# Membercounter won't shows members count

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Hi guys I have a problem so when I use the command it should show the number of users but it shows 0. How can i fix it?

**Code:**

```
    if(command === `${prefix}test`) {
      let guild = new Discord.Guild(600811118667235339);
      var memberCount = guild.members.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size;
      let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .addField("Liczba osob", `${memberCount}`)
      message.channel.send(embed)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create a new instance of a `Discord.Guild()` like this. You need to use something like that:

```js
let guild = message.client.guilds.get("600811118667235339");
```

It will get the guild which has for ID `600811118667235339`.